# Special Characters in SQL issue

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table A

a) The column1 has this text when I run my query "RENOVATIONREFRESH"

b) But when I extract the data I see this: "RENOVATIONREFRESHâ€‹"

c) I dont understand why cant I see the special characters in BQ. Only when I extract it I can see it.

I have a table B that I manually maintain.

a) column1 has text "RENOVATIONREFRESH" and column2 has text "TEST"

So when I try to join them through the name "RENOVATIONREFRESH" the join fails (it doesnt show any results).

I have tried entering both special characters in the manual table and without it but still the join fails.

Just dont know how to get around this issue.

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue. Not sure what `â€‹` should have been though!

Comment: I have also noticed that when I do CHAR_LENGTH(tableA.column1) I get 17. When I do CHAR_LENGTH(tableB.column1) I get 15 characters. How can I get tableA.column1 to be 15 characters. Is there a trim or something that I can use?

Comment: _"when I extract the data"_ How do you extract the data.

Comment: There is an option in BQ to extract the data in excel (csv)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I kinda solved it.

I just copy/pasted directly for the web the name and pasted into my excel. When then had 17 char.

But in realty it should only have 15 char. the 2 char are some some reason not visible.

When I run my query it show me this query "RENOVATIONREFRESH" There are 17 char here.
But when you do CHAR_LENGTH it shows 19 char. But for some reason the 2 char are not visible when viewing the query.

I would like to know how to "clean" this up so I only see 15 char.